# Read a random line from a file

Tags: c#, file, random

I'd like to put all the lines from my text file into a list and then select a random line to print. Is this possible? I have found a way to read all the lines in the file, but I can't find a way to print a specific line. preferably I'd just generate a random number and then print the corresponding line.

```cs
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"test.txt");
System.Console.WriteLine("Contents of test.txt = ");
Random rd = new Random();
int ball = rd.Next(0, 75);

foreach (string e in lines)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e);
}
     
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
System.Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Console.WriteLine(lines[ball]); instead foreach

Comment: yes, i was just an idiot and i was using the wrong brackets. please remove this question

Comment: @RamsesBeauBams You should be able to delete this question yourself.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the random number that you generate as index and access the line in the array using the `[ ]` indexing operator:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"test.txt");
Random rd = new Random();
int ball = rd.Next(0, lines.Length); // you can use the Length of the array to avoid jumping out of bounds

Console.WriteLine("Random line at line: " + ball);
Console.WriteLine(lines[ball]); // access here a line using your random number
```